# For loop is undefined when returned from a function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, return-value

Basically, I have a form submits the selected radio item. To detect the selected item, I used a for-each loop (standard one).

As you can see, I am able to return an object with the value of testVar to be used in another function constructor. However, the value of emotionSelected becomes undefined.

https://codepen.io/aguerrero/pen/PQopxw

```
var diaryUI = (function() {

    var emotionSelected, emotionList, testVar;

    emotionList = document.getElementsByName("emotion");

    for (var i = 0; i < emotionList.length; i++) {
        if (emotionList[i].checked) {
            emotionSelected = emotionList[i].value;
            break;
        }
    }

    testVar = "hello";

    return {
        getInput: function() {
            return {
                emotion: emotionSelected,
                test: testVar
            }
        }
    }

})();


var mainController = (function(diaryUICtrl) {

    var addEntry = function() {

        var input = diaryUICtrl.getInput();
        console.log(input);
    }

    document.getElementById("submit-entry").addEventListener("click", addEntry);


})(diaryUI);
```

However, if I move the for-each loop inside the method getInput, then it works.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Your code that tries to get the “currently” selected emotion only does so once, when the IIFE this is in is executed.

Comment: Just an observation, you could directly get your **emotionSelected** with the pseudo class selector **:checked** like that: `emotionSelected  = document.querySelector('[name="emotion"]:checked').value;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using something called *Self-Invoking-Function*, so, your initialized objects are being executed before you really submit your form.

```
(function () {
    // body of the function
}());
```

> The anonymous function above will be invoked right after it has been defined. The benefit of self-invoking functions is that they enable us to execute code once without cluttering the global namespace (without declaring any globals). [Reference](http://blog.mgechev.com/2012/08/29/self-invoking-functions-in-javascript-or-immediately-invoked-function-expression/)

Run this code snippet to see how your code executes the function `diaryUI` immediately.

```js
var diaryUI = (function() {
    var emotionSelected, emotionList, testVar;
    emotionList = document.getElementsByName("emotion");
    for (var i = 0; i < emotionList.length; i++) {
      console.log(emotionList[i].checked);
      if (emotionList[i].checked) {
        emotionSelected = emotionList[i].value;
        break;
      }
    }
    testVar = "hello";
    return {
      getInput: function() {
        return {
          emotion: emotionSelected,
          test: testVar
        }
      }
    }
  }

)();
var mainController = (function(diaryUICtrl) {
    var addEntry = function() {
      var input = diaryUICtrl.getInput();
      console.log(input);
    }
    document.getElementById("submit-entry").addEventListener("click", addEntry);
  }

)(diaryUI);
```

```html
<label for="emotion"></label>
<input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Happy" id="Happy"> Emotion 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Sad" id="Sad"> Emotion 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Neutral" id="Neutral"> Emotion 3
<br><br>
<a href="#" id="submit-entry">Submit Diary</a>
```

See? your code is being executed immediately at start.

You need to rethink how your declaring/implementing your functions.

This approach could help you, but you need to decide if you have to execute that code immediately

```js
var diaryUI = function() {
    var emotionSelected, emotionList, testVar;
    emotionList = document.getElementsByName("emotion");
    for (var i = 0; i < emotionList.length; i++) {
      console.log(emotionList[i].checked);
      if (emotionList[i].checked) {
        emotionSelected = emotionList[i].value;
        break;
      }
    }
    testVar = "hello";
    
        return {
          emotion: emotionSelected,
          test: testVar
        }
  }

var mainController = (function(diaryUICtrl) {
    var addEntry = function() {
      var input = diaryUI();
      console.log(input);
    }
    document.getElementById("submit-entry").addEventListener("click", addEntry);
  }
)();
```

```html
<label for="emotion"></label>
<input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Happy" id="Happy"> Emotion 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Sad" id="Sad"> Emotion 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Neutral" id="Neutral"> Emotion 3
<br><br>
<a href="#" id="submit-entry">Submit Diary</a>
```

Comment: But shouldn't "emotionSelected" be holding the value assigned, regardless of whether the function is immediately invoked? Why can't I access it anymore?

Comment: No, because none checkbox was checked. So, `emotionSelected` never was assigned.  This `diaryUICtrl.getInput()` only has the result of your immediately call.

Comment: Oh yeah true, my bad.. I missed that part. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The function after the assignment operator to `dairyUI` is running immediately, which is probably before the DOM is loaded. You probably want to have the DOM selection performed when the `getInput` runs instead, which by the way can be done more succinctly.

```
var diaryUI = (function() {

    var testVar = "hello";

    return {
      getInput: function() {
        return {
          emotion: (document.querySelector("[name=emotion]:checked") || {}).value,
          test: testVar
         }
      }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are immediately invoking `diaryUI` ([IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE))  before the click event even happens.

I would pass the `diaryUI` as a function reference and invoke it inside the click handler.

by the way, no need to wrap the function with parentheses if its to the right side of the equal sign (`=`). It is already an expression.

Running example:

```js
var diaryUI = function() {
  var emotionSelected, emotionList, testVar;

  emotionList = document.getElementsByName("emotion");

  for (var i = 0; i < emotionList.length; i++) {
    if (emotionList[i].checked) {
      emotionSelected = emotionList[i].value;
      break;
    }
  }

  testVar = "hello";

  return {
    getInput: function() {
      return {
        emotion: emotionSelected,
        test: testVar
      };
    }
  };
};

var mainController = (function(diaryUICtrl) {
  var addEntry = function() {
    var ctrl = diaryUICtrl();
    var input = ctrl.getInput();
    console.log(input);
  };

  document.getElementById("submit-entry").addEventListener("click", addEntry);
})(diaryUI);
```

```html
<label for="emotion"></label>
      <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Happy" id="Happy"> Emotion 1<br>
      <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Sad" id="Sad"> Emotion 2<br>
      <input type="radio" name="emotion" value="Neutral" id="Neutral"> Emotion 3
<br><br>
<a href="#" id="submit-entry">Submit Diary</a>
```